# @BeforeClass annotation is not working in dynamically created Test Suite

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have few **JUnit Tests** and I want to decide which one to use at runtime. I checked previous answers at SO and I ended up creating Test Suite dynamically.

This class is where my application starts. I have **CustomTestSuite** class and **Main** class adds Tests to my custom suite.

```
public class Main {

    public static junit.framework.TestSuite suite()
    {
        CustomTestSuite suite = new CustomTestSuite();

        suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(BTest.class));
        suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(ATest.class));

        return suite;
    }
}
```

**CustomTestSuite.java**

```
public class CustomTestSuite extends TestSuite {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Before class test");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("After class test");
    }

}
```

My **ATest** and **BTest** are simple Test classes, I will just show **ATest** as sample:

```
public class ATest{

    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        System.out.println("testMethod");
    }

 }
```

When I start running my project from **Main** class, it is expected to run the method with `@BeforeClass` first, do testing, and then run the method with `@AfterClass` annotation.

Tests are working fine but it skips `setUp` method and `tearDown` method. I tried `@Before` and `@BeforeClass` annotations both.

I am confused with suite structure. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`@Before` and  `@BeforeClass` are supposed to be used in `Test` class not in `TestSuite`. If need to have common `setUp` and `tearDown` for more than one Test class, then put those both methods in a super class and extend that super by `ATest` and `BTest` test classes. And also the Suite can be built and run simply with `@RunWith` and `@SuiteClasses` annotations and the `CustomTestSuite` class is not needed.

So the changes are as below.

The `CustomTestSuite` becomes `TestSuper`

```
public class TestSuper {
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Before class test");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("After class test");
    }
}
```

Now the `ATest` extends `TestSuper`

```
public class ATest extends TestSuper {
    @Test
    public void testMethod() {
        System.out.println("testMethod");
    }
}
```

Similarly `BTest` also should extend `TestSuper`. 
Simply add `@RunWith` and `@SuiteClasses` annotations to `Main` class as below and run `Main`.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ATest.class, BTest.class})
public class Main {

}
```

Have a go with these changes.

Comment: If I do do my `Main` class, I won't be able to add classes dynamically. I  have to declare them inside `@SuiteClasses` annotation. What I want is to add them at runtime as I did above. 
Also, if I do like this, assume that I will run `ATest` and `BTest`. So my `setUp` method will run before each class. WHat I want is `setUp()`-> `ATest` -> `BTest` -> `tearDown()`

Comment: How is your Main adding at runtime? For both ways the source code needs changing to add or remove test classes of the suite. And for your specific requirement to run `setUp` and `tearDown` once for the whole suite, move those two methods into `Main` with annotations, then the `TestSuper` class is not needed and `ATest`/`BTest` do not extend any class. Also remember to use correct annotations `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`.

Comment: `suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(BTest.class));`
I have a for loop in original version here, it filters and adds tests to suite. I am using BeforeClass/AfterClass I didn't post here exact code. Instead of using annotations I just added setUp method to Main class and I am calling it before testing starts, until I find better solution.

Comment: How are the class names ATest.class, BTest.class fed into the for loop?

Comment: I have an ArrayList of Class names, depending on their status, I filter them and add. If you are asking how I am getting Class from String,
`suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter( Class.forName( testPackage + t.getId() ) ));`